# How to show comments one time only for each department?

Tags: sql-server

I have results table and comments table :

This is select from lab_result_comments :

```
select dept_id,order_id,comments 
from Lab_Result_Comments 
where order_id = 2100000025
```

the output :

```
dept_id     order_id                  comments
2           2100000025             - comment 1 .
4           2100000025             - comment 2
```

And this is select from lab_results and select the comment if there is a comment because not always there is comments :

```
SELECT distinct [SAMPLE_ID]
      ,lab_results.[ORDER_ID]
      ,lab_results.[TESTID]
      ,lab_results.[GROUPID]
      ,[RESULT_NUMBER]
      ,[deptid]
      ,[patient_no]
      ,[custid]
      ,lab_results.[branch_id]
      ,Lab_Result_Comments.comments
  FROM [LAB_RESULTS]
  left join Lab_Result_Comments on LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID = Lab_Result_Comments.ORDER_ID
  where LAB_RESULTS.order_id = 2100000025
  order by LAB_RESULTS.testid,LAB_RESULTS.deptid
```

this is part of the current output :

```
ORDER_ID    RESULT_NUMBER   deptid  comments
2100000025  5.4              2              - Comment 1 
           
2100000025  100             2               - Comment 1 .
                                        
2100000025  61             2                - Comment 1.
                                        
                                           
2100000025  5.1           4             - Comment 2 
                                        
                                       
2100000025  85            4             - Comment 2
```

What I need :

1- How to select the comments one time only for each deptid if there is a comment in the department like this :

```
ORDER_ID    RESULT_NUMBER   deptid  comments
2100000025  5.4              2          -Comment 1
                     
2100000025  100             2              
                                            
2100000025  61              2             
                                            
2100000025  191             2              
2100000025  5.1             4               - Comment 2
                                            
2100000025  85             4               
2100000025  28.88          4
```

2- how to select the result only if there is no comments in table   Lab_Result_Comments like this :

```
ORDER_ID    RESULT_NUMBER   deptid  comments
    2100000025  5.4            2             
                                            
    2100000025  100             2              
                                            
    2100000025  61              2             
                                            
    2100000025  191             2              
    2100000025  5.1             4              
                                            
    2100000025  85              4              
    2100000025  28.88          4
```

3- Now if there is comments from 2 deptid the data duplicated twise or 3 times depends on the number of comments how to remove duplicates and select comments one time only for each department id ?

Comment: What is the primary key of the `LAB_RESULTS` table and why are you `DISTINCT`ing the query?

Comment: @Charlieface the primary key ID column in both tables and distinct to remove possible duplicates

Comment: You are trying to **format** result, this is not exactly what database is designed for, instead load data and format it in the application which using database.

Comment: Sorry, which column exactly and why would there be duplicates?

Comment: @Fabio how to change the design to show data as needed ?

Comment: Are you using some application to display results (c# console or web or other)? If so, load results and corresponding comments without formatting and format it in the application.

Comment: @Fabio yes I am using c# and print the results report using crystal reports

Answer (score 1):

to answer your first question , one way it to just show the comment for each first seen deptid :

```
SELECT distinct [SAMPLE_ID]
      ,lab_results.[ORDER_ID]
      ,lab_results.[TESTID]
      ,lab_results.[GROUPID]
      ,[RESULT_NUMBER]
      ,[deptid]
      ,[patient_no]
      ,[custid]
      ,lab_results.[branch_id]
      ,case row_number() over (partition by ORDER_ID,deptid order by LAB_RESULTS.testid,LAB_RESULTS.deptid) 
       when 1 then Lab_Result_Comments.comments
       else null
       end as comments
  FROM [LAB_RESULTS]
  left join Lab_Result_Comments on LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID = Lab_Result_Comments.ORDER_ID
  where LAB_RESULTS.order_id = 2100000025
  order by LAB_RESULTS.testid,LAB_RESULTS.deptid
```

Comment: in this SELECT it shows the comment for each deptid for first column but I need to show comment one time only if there is a comment for this deptid in comments table ..

Comment: @ZiadAdnan did you notice my change? did you try it? also I think you are missing joining on deptid as well, am i right?

Comment: yes it shows the comments one time for deptid = 2 , and one time for deptid = 4 , but i deleted the comment for deptid = 2 , but its still show comment  for one time for deptid = 2  i need to show comment for deptid when lab_results.deptid = Lab_Result_Comments .deptid , and if there is no comments show results only from LAB_RESULTS table

Comment: ok I thought its per deptid as your example shows different comments per deptid, I edited my answer , try now

Comment: sorry but  i tried it now its not work as expected if there is comment for deptid =1 and deptid = 2 it will show only first comment for deptid= 1 it will not show comment for deptid = 2 and comment for deptid = 3 and so on ?

Comment: then my first answer was correct , try now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226898/discussion-between-eshirvana-and-ziad-adnan).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to format result, this is not exactly what database is designed for, instead load data and format it in the application which using database.

*2- how to select the result only if there is no comments in table Lab_Result_Comments like this :*

```
SELECT distinct r.[SAMPLE_ID]
  ,r.[ORDER_ID]
  ,r.[TESTID]
  ,r.[GROUPID]
  ,r.[RESULT_NUMBER]
  ,r.[deptid]
  ,r.[patient_no]
  ,r.[custid]
  ,r.[branch_id]
FROM [LAB_RESULTS] r
WHERE LAB_RESULTS.order_id = 2100000025
  AND NOT EXISTS IN (SELECT * FROM Lab_Result_Comments c WHERE c.ORDER_ID = r.ORDER_ID
ORDER BY r.testid, r.deptid
```

Comment: this select will not select any data if there is no comments for this order in the table Lab_Result_Comments  then it will not select any data , i need to select the order result also if there is no comments  .

Comment: Sorry, it should be `NOT EXISTS` to return records without comments. _to select the result only if there is no comments in table Lab_Result_Comments_

Comment: its not show any result because there is a comments , i need it to be an option , select comments with result if there is comment and select results only if there is no comments , this select will select result if there is no comments , not this what i need .